# Convergence of the Series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1-(\ln 2)^{1 / n^2}\right) $

Tags: real-analysis

Check the Convergence of the
Series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1-(\ln 2)^{1 / n^2}\right) 
$$
My attempt: I feel that
$$
0\leq 1-(\ln 2)^\frac{1}{x^{2}} \leq \frac{1}{x^{2}}~~~ \forall x \in \mathbb R$$
to use direct comparison test, But unable to Prove it.

Comment: $\sum 1 $ is divergent series  !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: $\frac {e^{x}-1} x\to 1$ as $x \to 0$  (by series expansion or L'Hopital's Rule) so $|e^{x}-1| <2|x|$ whenever $|x|$ is sufficiently small. Take $x=\frac  1 {n^{2}} \ln \ln 2$.

Comment: typo $x=\ln(\ln(2))/n^2$

Comment: @zwim Yes, thank you.

Comment: Or, when $-1<x<0,$ the power series for $e^x$ is alternating $\pm$ and the absolute values of its terms are decreasing, so $1+x<e^x<1.$

Comment: "by series expansion or L'Hopital's Rule" Or by definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 2):

You can bound your series from above by a convergent one using the binomial series as follows:

- Set $q= \ln 2 \Rightarrow 0<q<1$ and let $p=1-q$. Hence,
  $$1-\left(\ln 2 \right)^{\frac 1{n^2}} = 1-q^{\frac 1{n^2}} = 1-(1-p)^{\frac 1{n^2}}$$
- Taylor on $(1-p)^{\frac 1{n^2}}$ gives

$$(1-p)^{\frac 1{n^2}} = 1-\frac 1{n^2}p - \frac 12\cdot \frac 1{n^2}\left(1-\frac 1{n^2}\right)\xi_n^2 \text{ with } 0 < \xi_n < p$$

So, for $n>1$ you have

$$(1-p)^{\frac 1{n^2}} > 1-\frac 1{n^2}p \Rightarrow 1-(1-p)^{\frac 1{n^2}} < \frac 1{n^2}p$$

So, you have for $n>1$:

$$1-\left(\ln 2 \right)^{\frac 1{n^2}} < \frac 1{n^2}(1-\ln 2)$$

which shows the convergence.